# Textmate: How to export Themes?

Tags: mac, themes, export, textmate

I created a new theme in textmate in `preferences->fonts & colors`, and I would like to share it with my friend. But I don't know how to export it.

It would be logical to save my theme automatically to `Applications/Textmate/Contents/ShareSupport/Themes` but I can't find my new theme there.

So how can I create a `my_theme_name.tmTheme` file from my theme ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you edit a theme and exit TextMate's preferences, it will be saved in

```
~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Themes
```

---

**How to create a new theme from scratch:**

If you don't see it there, it might not have been saved. I just tried this and it seems to be buggy when you create a copy of an already existing theme.

Make sure you:

- go to Preferences, Fonts & Colors, Edit Theme List and
- then click the <kbd>+</kbd> button (to create a completely new theme) or <kbd>++</kbd> button (to copy an existing theme)
- give it a proper name
- close the dialogue and edit the theme
- close the preferences

Then it should be saved.

Comment: thanks for your answer, Hmm, I've done exactly this(from scratch) but I don't even have a `TextMate` folder in my `~/Library/Application Support/` folder :|

Comment: Really? This is where it should be, I just tested it again: [http://i.imgur.com/SqtmV.png](http://i.imgur.com/SqtmV.png)

Comment: Whops I've forgot the `~` . It's here thanks very very much!